# BeautifulSoup and List indexing

Tags: list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, slice, findall

As I am still quite new to web scraping I am currently practicing some basics such as this one. I have scraped the categories from 'th' tag and the players from the 'tr' tag and appended it to a couple empty lists. The categories come out fine from get_text(), but when I try printing the players it has a number rank before the first letter of the name, and the player's team abbreviation letters after the last name.
3 things I am trying to do:

1)output only the first and last name of each player by doing some slicing from the list but I cannot figure out any easier way to do it.  There is probably a quicker way inside the tags where I can call the class or using soup.findAll again in the html, or something else I am unware of, but I currently do not know how or what I am missing.

2)take the number ranks before the name and append it to an empty list.

3)take the 3 last abbreviated letters and append it to an empty list

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

players = []
categories = []

url ='https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc'
source = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4(source.text, 'lxml')

for i in soup.findAll('th'):
    c = i.get_text()
    categories.append(c)

for i in soup.findAll('tr'):
    player = i.get_text()
    players.append(player)

players = players[1:51]

print(categories)
print(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apis are always the best way to go in my opinion.

However, this can also be done with `pandas` `.read_html()` (it uses beautifulsoup under the hood to parse the table).

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc'

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
dfs[0][['Name','Team']] = dfs[0]['Name'].str.extract('^(.*?)([A-Z]+)$', expand=True)
df = dfs[0].join(dfs[1])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df[['RK','Name','Team','POS']])

    RK                     Name  Team POS
0    1             James Harden   HOU  SG
1    2            Stephen Curry    GS  PG
2    3             Bradley Beal   WSH  SG
3    4               Trae Young   ATL  PG
4    5             Kevin Durant   BKN  SF
5    6              CJ McCollum   POR  SG
6    7             Kyrie Irving   BKN  PG
7    8             Jaylen Brown   BOS  SG
8    9    Giannis Antetokounmpo   MIL  PF
9   10             Jayson Tatum   BOS  PF
10  11           Damian Lillard   POR  PG
11  12              Luka Doncic   DAL  PG
12  13            Collin Sexton   CLE  PG
13  14              Paul George   LAC  SG
14  15           Brandon Ingram    NO  SF
15  16             Nikola Jokic   DEN   C
16  17             LeBron James   LAL  SF
17  18              Zach LaVine   CHI  SG
18  19           Christian Wood   HOU  PF
19  20            Kawhi Leonard   LAC  SF
20  21              Joel Embiid   PHI   C
21  22             Jerami Grant   DET  PF
22  23            Anthony Davis   LAL  PF
23  24             Jamal Murray   DEN  PG
24  25            Julius Randle    NY  PF
25  26          Malcolm Brogdon   IND  PG
26  27            Fred VanVleet   TOR  SG
27  28           Nikola Vucevic   ORL   C
28  28         Donovan Mitchell  UTAH  SG
29  30             Terry Rozier   CHA  PG
30  31             Devin Booker   PHX  SG
31  32          Khris Middleton   MIL  SF
32  33            Terrence Ross   ORL  SG
33  33           Victor Oladipo   IND  SG
34  35        Russell Westbrook   WSH  PG
35  36         Domantas Sabonis   IND  PF
36  36             De'Aaron Fox   SAC  PG
37  38          Zion Williamson    NO  SF
38  39            Tobias Harris   PHI  SF
39  40              Bam Adebayo   MIA   C
40  41            DeMar DeRozan    SA  SG
41  41         D'Angelo Russell   MIN  SG
42  43           Gordon Hayward   CHA  SF
43  44               Kyle Lowry   TOR  PG
44  44  Shai Gilgeous-Alexander   OKC  SG
45  46              Mike Conley  UTAH  PG
46  47            Malik Beasley   MIN  SG
47  48               RJ Barrett    NY  SG
48  49            Thomas Bryant   WSH   C
49  50            Pascal Siakam   TOR  PF
```

Comment: this looks clean too, using regex is too much for me at the moment, since ive only looked up 1 tutorial on it. using pandas .read_html() to parse the table, i guess i get it. just the syntax of that middle line is a bit hard for me to visualize.

Comment: Ya so the text in table has the player name with team together Ie. Kyle LowryTOR. So all that’s doing is taking the all caps at the tail of the string, and splits it. So [Kyle LowryTOR] becomes [Kyle Lowry, TOR]. And then we just put it into 2 columns. Ya I’m still trying to learn regex as well.

Comment: And pandas will return all tables into a list. The first table is the player rank and name. The 2nd table is the stats. So that’s what I join. I only printed the columns you wanted though. If you do 'print (df)' you’ll see it has the stats too

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

url = "https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

table_data = [
    [r // 2, i.find("a").getText(), i.find("span").getText()] for r, i in
    enumerate(soup.find_all("td", class_="Table__TD"), start=1)
    if i.find("a") and i.find("span")
]

print(tabulate(table_data, headers=["Rank", "Name", "Team"], tablefmt="pretty"))
```

Output:

```
| Rank |          Name           | Team |
+------+-------------------------+------+
|  1   |      James Harden       | HOU  |
|  2   |      Stephen Curry      |  GS  |
|  3   |      Bradley Beal       | WSH  |
|  4   |       Trae Young        | ATL  |
|  5   |      Kevin Durant       | BKN  |
|  6   |       CJ McCollum       | POR  |
|  7   |      Kyrie Irving       | BKN  |
|  8   |      Jaylen Brown       | BOS  |
|  9   |  Giannis Antetokounmpo  | MIL  |
|  10  |      Jayson Tatum       | BOS  |
|  11  |     Damian Lillard      | POR  |
|  12  |       Luka Doncic       | DAL  |
|  13  |      Collin Sexton      | CLE  |
|  14  |       Paul George       | LAC  |
|  15  |     Brandon Ingram      |  NO  |
|  16  |      Nikola Jokic       | DEN  |
|  17  |      LeBron James       | LAL  |
|  18  |       Zach LaVine       | CHI  |
|  19  |     Christian Wood      | HOU  |
|  20  |      Kawhi Leonard      | LAC  |
|  21  |       Joel Embiid       | PHI  |
|  22  |      Jerami Grant       | DET  |
|  23  |      Anthony Davis      | LAL  |
|  24  |      Jamal Murray       | DEN  |
|  25  |      Julius Randle      |  NY  |
|  26  |     Malcolm Brogdon     | IND  |
|  27  |      Fred VanVleet      | TOR  |
|  28  |     Nikola Vucevic      | ORL  |
|  29  |    Donovan Mitchell     | UTAH |
|  30  |      Terry Rozier       | CHA  |
|  31  |      Devin Booker       | PHX  |
|  32  |     Khris Middleton     | MIL  |
|  33  |      Terrence Ross      | ORL  |
|  34  |     Victor Oladipo      | IND  |
|  35  |    Russell Westbrook    | WSH  |
|  36  |    Domantas Sabonis     | IND  |
|  37  |      De'Aaron Fox       | SAC  |
|  38  |     Zion Williamson     |  NO  |
|  39  |      Tobias Harris      | PHI  |
|  40  |       Bam Adebayo       | MIA  |
|  41  |      DeMar DeRozan      |  SA  |
|  42  |    D'Angelo Russell     | MIN  |
|  43  |     Gordon Hayward      | CHA  |
|  44  |       Kyle Lowry        | TOR  |
|  45  | Shai Gilgeous-Alexander | OKC  |
|  46  |       Mike Conley       | UTAH |
|  47  |      Malik Beasley      | MIN  |
|  48  |       RJ Barrett        |  NY  |
|  49  |      Thomas Bryant      | WSH  |
|  50  |      Pascal Siakam      | TOR  |
+------+-------------------------+------+
```

Comment: this looks clean, except im not familiar with tabulate module. i dont really understand the table_data variable. no idea what r//2 does? floor division is one operator i mostly confused of when to use in real use cases. but appreciate it your response, i will prob have to look up some tutorials on tabulate

Comment: You do not have to use `tabulate` think baduker just used it to display data in a pretty way. You can push `table_data` to a dataframe as well -> `pd.DataFrame(table_data, columns=["Rank", "Name", "Team"])`  -  I Like the list comprehension  cause it looks more compact then a common for loop view, but for new ones seems it is harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

**Always ask you - Is there an easier way?**

Yes it is and you should go it :)

If you wanna scrape, first take a look if you really have to scrape content from the website or if there is an `api` that provide the information well structured.

**Example requesting api**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/basketball/nba/statistics/byathlete?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&isqualified=true&page=1&limit=50&sort=offensive.avgPoints%3Adesc&season=2021&seasontype=2"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()

ranking=[]

for i,player in enumerate(response.json()['athletes'], start=1):
    rank = i
    name = player['athlete']['displayName']
    team = player['athlete']['teamShortName']
    category = player['athlete']['position']['abbreviation']
    ranking.append({'rank':rank, 'name':name, 'team':team, 'category':category})

df = pd.DataFrame(ranking)
df
```

**Output data frame**

```
rank                     name  team category
    1             James Harden   HOU       SG
    2            Stephen Curry    GS       PG
    3             Bradley Beal   WSH       SG
    4               Trae Young   ATL       PG
    5             Kevin Durant   BKN       SF
    6              CJ McCollum   POR       SG
    7             Kyrie Irving   BKN       PG
    8             Jaylen Brown   BOS       SG
    9    Giannis Antetokounmpo   MIL       PF
   10             Jayson Tatum   BOS       PF
```

**But to answer your question**

You can also do it with `BeautifulSoup`, but it is much more error-prone in my opinion:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

data = []

url ='https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/table/offensive/sort/avgPoints/dir/desc'
source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

for i in soup.select('tr')[1:]:
    if i.select_one('td'):
        rank = i.select_one('td').get_text()
    if i.select_one('div > a'):
        player = i.select_one('div > a').get_text()
    if i.select_one('div > span'):
        team =i.select_one('div > span').get_text()
                  
    data.append({'rank':rank, 'player':player, 'team':team})

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

If you do not wanna use css selectors, you can also do

```
for i in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    if i.find('td'):
        rank = i.find('td').get_text()
    if i.find('a'):
        player = i.find('a').get_text()
    if i.find('span'):
        team =i.find('span').get_text()
```

Comment: ok this code above with using api looks more familiar for me to understand, except i am having the hardest time how to use that api. I have looked up many tutorials on api but still cannot understand it naturally. the bs example looks harder to understand for me. is that > operator mean div is greater than a?  this format looks clean too appreciate that response.

Comment: No problem, I updated the second example for you to a running version -  I worked with [css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and the `div > a` means select  `<a>` directly beneath the `<div>` but you can use the `find()` and `find_all()` as well.